# Can the expected value of a random variable be a function of other random variables?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $Y$, $Z$, and $L$ be random variables and the possible value of a uniformly distributed random variable $X$ can be expressed by the following inequality

$$Y+Z-L \le X \le Y+Z$$

Can we say that $E(X)$,the expected value of $X$, is $Y+Z-\frac 12L$? Is it meaningful to calculate the expected value of $E(X)$? In other words, is it correct to express $E(X)$ as $E(Y)+E(Z)-\frac12 E(L)$?

Comment: The last question is not the other questions "in other words".

Comment: You can say $E(Y)+E(Z)-E(L) \leq E(X) \leq E(Y)+E(Z)$, you cannot know the expected value of $X$ from the information given.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean that, given $Y, Z$ and $L$, $X$ is uniform in the interval $[Y+Z-L, Y+Z]$, then you could say $E[X|Y,Z,L] = Y + Z - L/2$ and
$E[X] = E[Y] + E[Z] - E[L]/2$.